# Day name in english despite diffrent locale

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I need to get the name of the day in my native language(polish, pl).
So I do:

```
echo (new \DateTimeImmutable())->format('D'));
```

And the response is in English: `Thu`, despite that the `locale` is set to `pl`.
To confirm that, the output of this line `\Locale::getDefault()` is `pl`.

What could be wrong?

I am using php 7.3, symfony 4.4

Answer (score 2):

The `format()` method does not use locales, if you look into the [php.net documentation:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

> This method does not use locales. All output is in English.

If you have the `intl` [extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php) installed you could use `IntlDateFormatter::format` instead.